# A parameter keeps undefined after it had been defined by imperatively calling the Apex method that returns wrapper class

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm still a new developer to LWC.

I tried to set a parameter by imperatively calling the Apex method that returns the wrapper class.

I've confirmed that it's successfully renders the object on the console by console.log in the same method that defines a parameter,

But when I try to use it after that process, it's still undefined and unable to render the component using that parameter on DOM.

What am I missing for setting the parameter and render it on DOM?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { LightningElement , track } from 'lwc';
import getWorkShifts from '@salesforce/apex/LWCWorkShiftController.getWorkShifts';

export default class Workshiftwrapper extends LightningElement {
    YYMM = '2020-08';
    @track workshifts;
    error;

    handleSearchShift() {
        getWorkShifts({ YYMM: this.YYMM })
            .then((result) => {
                this.error = undefined;
                this.workshifts = result;

                console.log('check1 object will be returned' + this.workshifts);                   
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.workshifts = undefined;
                this.error = error;
            });
        console.log('check2 workshifts will be undefined'+ this.workshifts);   
    }
}
```

```
<template>
    <!--this should be rendered after setting the parameter but not rendered-->
    <div>    
        <p class="slds-m-bottom_small">
                <lightning-button label="search" onclick={handleSearchShift}> 
                </lightning-button>
            </p>
    </div>
    <div class="eachworkshift">
        <template if:true={workshifts}>
            <template for:each={workshifts.data} for:item="workshift">
                <c-workday
                    key={workshift.dateOfMonth}
                    workday={workshift}>
                </c-workday>
            </template>
        </template>
    </div>
    <template if:true={error}>
        eror
    </template>
</template>
```

```
public class LWCWorkShiftController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<WorkShiftWrapper> getWorkShifts(String YYMM){
        String StrYYMM = YYMM;

        //irelevant processes

        return WorkShiftWrappers;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling the method 'handleSearchShift'?
Your second console statement will always return undefined as the apex method is still executing.

Comment: I've added div. Thank you. Asynchronous processing made me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is incorrect; you only use this with *wired methods*:

```
<template for:each={workshifts.data} for:item="workshift">
```

Instead, refer just to `workshifts` itself:

```
<template for:each={workshifts} for:item="workshift">
```

This is demonstrated in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex):

```
handleLoad() {
    getContactList()
        .then(result => {
            this.contacts = result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

---

```
        <template if:true={contacts}>
            <template for:each={contacts} for:item="contact">
                <p key={contact.Id}>{contact.Name}</p>
            </template>
        </template>
```

Comment: That's worked!!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you are missing the getter method which will return you the value of `workshifts`

In your javascript code can you please add below code

```
get workshifts() {
    return this.workshifts;
}
```

This will return the value to the DOM. Have a look at the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_props_getters_setters)

Comment: No explicit getter is necessary to access a variable. If you've been doing it this way, you've been writing far too much code.

Comment: your answer is correct. No need of getter

Comment: thank you everybody,